# Make fragment totally inside framelayout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-framelayout

In my app, I want to keep a same Ad banner at the bottom of all the screens, so I use one Activity with multiple fragments.

In the Activity's layoutfile(activity_mail.xml), I have a FrameLayout as the container of the fragments and a AdView at the bottom to show the banner Ads from Admob.

```
 <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/adFragment"
            android:name="com.jiyuzhai.wangxizhishufazidian.MainActivity$AdFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Layout of the fragment to replace the existing fragment

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/theme_color"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Topbar in fragment"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/theme_color"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:text="Bottombar in fragment"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="30sp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Code to replace the existing fragment

```
fragment = new LinmoFragment();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
fragmentTransaction.setCustomAnimations(R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out, R.anim.fade_in, R.anim.fade_out);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

But when I replace the fragments in the container, the bottom area of the  fragment was hide by the AdView, in other words, the fragment was out of the Framelayout, I want the fragment totally inside the container. is that possible?

The following is what I want

[image]

and this is what I get(The Ad banner hide the bottombar of the fragment)

[image]

Any idea?

By the way, I find there is no way to keep a same banner for all screens with multiple Activities in Android, many people on SO said you need to use Single Activities with multiple fragments, then you can add/remove your fragments dynamically without reload new banner, but, there is no code found for this approach, so I try it myself. if you have better solutions, please help me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".MainActivity"
        tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame">
        <fragment
            android:id="@+id/adFragment"
            android:name="com.jiyuzhai.wangxizhishufazidian.MainActivity$AdFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_above="@id/adFragment" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The changes I made to your original layout file were moving the adFragment definition above the frame layout, made the frame layout height wrap content, and added the `layout_above` attribute to make the frame layout appear above the ad fragment.

An alternative approach would have been to use a vertical linear layout with the frame layout first with a layout weight of 1 (and the ad fragment would not have a layout weight).

By the way, the fragment is contained completely within your frame layout.  The frame layout was just being overlapped by the ad fragment in your original layout.  The above suggestion makes it so that there is no overlap.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, works after adding this line `android:layout_above="@id/adFragment`

Answer (score 1):

If you want to both avoid overlapping and make the container fill the screen then you should just change RelativeLayout to LinearLayout.

```
 <LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity"
    tools:ignore="MergeRootFrame"
    android:orientation:"vertical"
    >
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"  />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/adFragment"
        android:name="com.jiyuzhai.wangxizhishufazidian.MainActivity$AdFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```